# Nodejs- how to get access to query object in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code in my Node API.

```
const config = require('config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = db = {};

initialize();

async function initialize() {
    // create db if it doesn't already exist
    const { host, port, user, password, database } = config.database;
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host, port, user, password });
    await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${database}\`;`);

    // connect to db
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { dialect: 'mysql' });

    // init models and add them to the exported db object
    db.User = require('../users/user.model')(sequelize);
    db.Aircraft = require('../aircrafts/aircraft.model')(sequelize);
    db.Manufacturer = require('../manufacturers/manufacturer.model')(sequelize);
    db.ModelMedia = require('../model_media/model_media.model')(sequelize);
    db.ModelScale = require('../model_scales/model_scale.model')(sequelize);
    db.AircraftGroup = require('../aircraft_groups/aircraft_group.model')(sequelize);
    db.AircraftModel = require('../aircraftmodels/aircraftmodel.model')(sequelize);
    
    // sync all models with database
    await sequelize.sync();
}
```

Now I want to call a raw query but I cant get access to the the "query" object when with this
code in a service module using this code for example because the query object isn't accessible.

```
const db = require('_helpers/db');

  sql = `SELECT sum(cnt) as totalCount FROM (`
    sql += `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT aircraft_id) as cnt FROM aircraft INNER JOIN aircraftmodels using (aircraft_id) `;
    sql += `WHERE ${whereclause}`;
    sql += `) d`;
    const [result, meta] = await db.query(sql, { raw: true });
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Side note: I would suggest not to build query dynamically, as you are open to SQL Injections attacks by hackers.